# Use of variables in Bitbucket custom steps

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have this custom defined step:

```
definitions:
    steps:
      - step: &var-test
        name: Var test
        script:
          - ssh ${HOST} "source ~/.bash_profile; cd domains/\${ALIAS}.example.com; ls -la"
```

This step is used like this:

```
- step:
  <<: *var-test
  name: Var test
  variables:
    - ALIAS: 'test.'
```

HOST is a Repository Variable set in Bitbucket settings and works. I know this because it logs in to my host. Bitbucket has no issues with my YAML and runs the steps and scripts.

However, it doesn't seem to pass the value of the ALIAS variable. I've tried many variants like:

- $ALIAS
- ${ALIAS}
- "$ALIAS"

It is always blank.

The output I get in the pipeline:

```
+ ssh ${HOST} "source ~/.bash_profile; cd domains/\${ALIAS}.example.com; ls -la"
bash: line 1: cd: domains/.example.com: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Unless it's a custom step you cannot define variables for the step. For the correct formatting for a custom step see https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-start-conditions/#Custom--manual--pipelines